# Should the logo tag be renamed to logo-language?

Tags: discussion, tags, ambiguous-tags

On Stack Overflow, the `logo` tag is used to refer to the [logo language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003841/how-do-i-move-the-turtle-in-logo) and also to refer to [logos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/508481/how-would-you-display-a-3d-banana-in-c). The latter is also used in Meta Stack Overflow.

Is the latter tag a legitimate one? If so, should we move questions referring to the former to the tag `logo-language`? How do I move the questions?

Comment: [tag:logo-language] exists but I am getting a "Try using an existing tag instead." error msg

Comment: I’m wondering whether [renaming these tags might lead to less mis-tagging](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189665/no-really-should-the-logo-tag-be-renamed-to-logo-language).

Comment: I was actually about to post a question "How can I find questions about Logo (the language)?" when I saw this.  If the consensus is that the Logo tag refers to the language, I will start removing it whenever I see it misused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the 2nd usage is probably an incorrect usage, at least in the context of tagging on Stackoverflow. The "argument" that it's used differently on MSO shouldn't hold any weight as they're entirely separate sites with different sets of tags so the usage of a tag for one "thing" on one of the sites shouldn't particularly influence the usage of it on the other.

I'd also prefer, although not being an active participant in questions tagged `logo` my opinion doesn't (and indeed shouldn't!) count for much, that `logo` remain as just that, rather than `logo-language`. Or should we rename `javascript` to `javascript-language`, for example?

Comment: I’m wondering whether [renaming these tags might lead to less mis-tagging](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/189665/no-really-should-the-logo-tag-be-renamed-to-logo-language).

Comment: "Or should we rename `javascript` to `javascript-language`, for example?" is a really weird example, as javascript did not exist before and still is not a common noun apart from the programming language. Perhaps `Java` would be a better example, except the point still stands that we only need to worry about collisions that people are likely to tag, and until coffee maker hacking becomes popular on SO, `Java` is likely a confusion free tag.

Comment: Honestly, Logo the language *should* (in hindsight) have been named something else.  Have you ever tried to Google for answers on Logo syntax?  You end up appending the word "turtle" to every query (even if you're not doing turtle graphics) just to filter out irrelevant results.