# Could you add a duplicate tag? (case sensitive)

Tags: feature-request, tags

Could you add a new LOGO tag **and** still keep the existing [logo](/questions/tagged/logo) tag?

related: [Should the logo tag be renamed to logo-language?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63452/)

Comment: I don't see any use of the tag `logo` as in `graphic` on SO, SU or SF...you might want to clarify what you want to accomplish?

Comment: @bobby you should click on the tag

Answer (score 2):

No, tags are case-insensitive.  (Actually, tags do not allow uppercase characters)

Consider creating a workaround like [logo-language](/questions/tagged/logo-language) for the language.

Comment: Yes and I am asking if they could add an exception in case of problematic tags like this one which covers logos (symbol or logotype) and the language (LOGO)

Comment: @Knu, you will need to qualify the tag with some more data.

Comment: @nelson *users with less than 1500 reputation can't create new tags. The tag 'logo-language' is new.* (can't use it)