# No, really — should the logo tag be renamed to logo-language?

Tags: discussion, tags

Stack Overflow has a “[logo](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/logo)” tag for questions about the programming language Logo, and a “[graphical-logo](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/graphical-logo)” tag for questions about logos (e.g. getting them to display correctly on web pages).

Yesterday I looked at how many questions used each tag:

- logo: ~80
- graphical-logo: ~85

However, around 50 of the questions tagged “logo” (almost all of which were in the most recent 50) were referring to graphical logos, rather than the programming language. I went through and corrected them (it was a slow afternoon at work), leaving:

- logo: 30
- graphical logo: 135

It seems that, at least recently, when users type “logo” into the tag field, they’re almost always talking about graphical logos, not Logo the language, but don’t realise that graphical-logo is the appropriate tag.

I know this isn’t by any means a big problem, but I was wondering whether renaming the tags (from “logo” to “logo-language”, and “graphical-logo” to “logo”), or possibly doing some sort of special-case thing in the tag autocomplete, might result in fewer mis-tagged logo/Logo questions.

Previously suggested here: [Should the logo tag be renamed to logo-language?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63452/should-the-logo-tag-be-renamed-to-logo-language)

Comment: I was just about to post an answer that said something along the lines of "there is no need for a tag that refers to graphical logos", then I found out that such an answer was already posted to the linked question...

Comment: @CodyGray: do you mean there is no need *for* a tag referring to graphical logos?

Comment: @CodyGray: ah, yes — I’ve re-read that answer, and it does say that. It’s definitely arguable that there’s no need for a graphical-logo tag on Stack Overflow: I’d need to review the questions properly, but for most of them, the tag didn’t add much additional information.

Comment: @CodyGray: However, it still might help to rename “logo” to “logo-language” — users asking about logos might be less likely to accidentally apply a tag called “logo-language” than a tag called “logo”.

Comment: And if “logo” doesn’t exist as a tag, users need 1500 rep to create it.

Comment: (Although it says [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125234/a-real-solution-to-ambiguous-tags) that the rep requirement "hasn't been deterring users from creating unnecessary or redundant tags".)